# Do I need to "unbind" pca953x driver from GPIO devices on embedded platform in order to read from device?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, usrp

I've been having an issue reading from GPIO devices on an embedded device (usrp n310). `i2cdetect` gives "UU" for the particular devices that I'm trying to reach indicating that the devices are already being occupied by a chip. */sys/bus/i2c/drivers* shows that the driver linked to these devices is the pca953x. Previously, I was able to read and write from a GPIO device (tca6416) on the zc706 platform, however, when doing a comparison of */sys/bus/i2c/drivers*, I don't see any drivers associated with that chip. The code that I'm using is the following

```cpp
#include "i2c_dev.hpp" 

int main()  
{ 
  int i2cfd; 
  __s32 num; 

  // Opening i2c adapter 6  
  printf("Opening bus adapter\n");
  i2cfd = open("/dev/i2c-6", O_RDWR); 
  if ( i2cfd < 0 ) {
    printf("Failed to open /dev/i2c-6: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  // Instatiating three objects of IO_Expander class 
  IO_Expander dba; 

  // Reading data from the IO Expander
  printf("Setting slave address of device\n");
  if (ioctl(i2cfd, I2C_SLAVE, 0x20) < 0) {
    printf("Error setting slave address:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Reading data from the IO Expander for DB-A Object\n");

  num = dba.read_data(i2cfd, 0x00);
  if (num < 0) {
    printf("Error reading data: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  } else {
    printf("The input value is %d\n", num);
  }

  printf("Leaving DB-A Object\n\n\n");

  // Closing the adapter
  close(i2cfd);
}
```

So, am I unable to read from the GPIO devices on the n310 platform because of this pca953x driver? If so, would a correct approach be to "unbind" the pca953x driver the from the devices in order to read values from them?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What’s the expectation here? Why do you need to unbound the kernel driver?

Comment: @0andriy there's a chip(tca6408) on the n310 that I'm trying to read values from that I'm unable to because it appears to be in use by the pca953x driver. I'll edit my original post

Comment: **Why** do you need to read them? **What for**? (You probably didn't get why we have kernel drivers in the fist place)

Comment: What is currently using the GPIO lines provided by the I/O expander, and can you unbind those GPIO lines rather than unbind the I/O expander itself?

Comment: pca953x is the driver for the TCA6416 chip.